# How do i copy test report to different directory using maven as build tool

Tags: java, maven, testing, automated-tests

I am executing automation test using fail-safe plugin.Once the execution is completed it generates the result in target folder.I would like to copy and save it in another folder to keep all the older results.How do i achieve this. Am using maven as my build tool

Answer (score 0):

You can try and configure a [custom report location](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/examples/report-custom-location.html)

```
<configuration>
      <outputDirectory>${basedir}/somewhere/newsite</outputDirectory>
</configuration>
```

Alsternatively use the [`reportsDirectories`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/failsafe-report-only-mojo.html#reportsDirectories) tag to specify the directory for reports.